# Failing to test Devise with Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, testing, capybara

I'm building a Rails 3 app using Devise, with Capybara for UI testing.  The following test is failing:

```
class AuthenticationTest < ActionController::IntegrationTest

  def setup
    @user = User.create!(:email => 'test@example.com', 
                         :password => 'testtest', 
                         :password_confirmation => 'testtest')
    @user.save!
    Capybara.reset_sessions!
  end

  test "sign_in" do
    # this proves the user exists in the database ...
    assert_equal 1, User.count
    assert_equal 'test@example.com', User.first.email

    # ... but we still can't log in ...
    visit '/users/sign_in'
    assert page.has_content?('Sign in')
    fill_in :user_email, :with => 'test@example.com'
    fill_in :user_password, :with => 'testtest'
    click_button('user_submit')

    # ... because this test fails
    assert page.has_content?('Signed in successfully.')
  end

end
```

... but I have no idea why.  As you can see from the code, the user is being created in the database; I'm using the same approach to create the user as I did in seeds.rb.

If I run the test through the debugger, I can see the user in the database and verify that the page is loading.  But still the authentication fails; I can verify this because if I change the assertion to test for the failure case, the test passes:

```
# verify that the authentication actually failed
assert page.has_content?('Invalid email or password.')
```

I'm used to Rails 2, & using Selenium for this sort of testing, so I suspect I'm doing something daft.  Could someone please point me in the right direction here?

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. In my instance, it only fails authentication when I'm using a JS driver. If I test without JS support, there is no problem.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I was having the same issue and found [a thread with a solution](http://groups.google.com/group/ruby-capybara/browse_thread/thread/97bfecbcf9c242dc?pli=1):

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end

end
```

For the DatabaseCleaner stuff to work you'll need to include the `database_cleaner` gem. If you haven't used it before, you may need to `rake db:test:prepare` before rerunning your tests. I hope this works for you, too!

Comment: I had the same issue, this post solved my problem http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2011/12/three-tips-to-improve-the-performance-of-your-test-suite/

my use_transactional_fixtures is set to true (which is faster than database cleaner), but now I share the same database connection between the web server and test suite, so the webserver can "see" what I created on the test suite.

Comment: Also see [Avdi Grimm's post](http://devblog.avdi.org/2012/08/31/configuring-database_cleaner-with-rails-rspec-capybara-and-selenium/) where the `:js => true` option is used in `spec/support/database_cleaner.rb`

Answer (score 3):

I've run into a similar problem before.  Setting the password directly has some weird effects because it's supposed to be encrypted and stored with a salt--sometimes it works for me and other times it doesn't.  I have a hard time remembering which specific cases were problematic.  I'd recommend the following, in this order (for simplicity)

- Verify that the password field is getting filled in properly and passed as the right param (not necessary if you're using Devise's autogenerated view and haven't touched it)

  - if your site can run in development mode (i.e. no log in bugs), then just boot it up and log in manually
  - If not, insert `debugger` as the first line in your `sessions_controller`.  Then check `params` and make sure the password is correct and in `params[:user][:password]`.

    If you didn't override Devise's `sessions_controller`, then you can find your Devise path with `bundle show devise`.  Then look for the `create` action within `(devise path)/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb`
- Change your test setup to create a user through the web interface, to ensure the password gets set properly, then try running your test again

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with a setup fairly similar to yours. In my case, switching to ActiveRecord sessions in the initializer solved the problem.

Additionally, make sure you call @user.skip_confirmation! if you are using the "confirmable" module in devise.