# Rspec capybara User cannot login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, capybara

Testing devise sign in using capybara. It seems something is wrong as i cannot test sign in using rspec and capybara. Im using factory girl to define user

```
FactoryGirl.define do
 factory :user do
  email 'admin@revol-tech.com.np'
  password 'bhaktapur'
  password_confirmation 'bhaktapur'
  admin true
  name 'admin'
  confirmation_sent_at "#{DateTime.now}"
  confirmation_token 'anupsumhikichiki'
  confirmed_at "#{DateTime.now}"
  username 'username'
 end
end
```

Here is my spec_helper.rb

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'database_cleaner'
# FactoryGirl.find_definitions
Capybara.current_driver = :selenium
# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
# in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}
RSpec.configure do |config|
 config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
 config.before(:suite) do
 DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
 DatabaseCleaner.clean_with :truncation
end

config.before(:each) do
 DatabaseCleaner.start
end
# config.after(:each) {  }
config.after(:each) do
 DatabaseCleaner.clean
 Warden.test_reset!
end
config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

# If true, the base class of anonymous controllers will be inferred
# automatically. This will be the default behavior in future versions of
# rspec-rails.
config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false
end
```

And here is my spec

```
require_relative '../spec_helper.rb'
include Warden::Test::Helpers
Warden.test_mode!

feature "the signin process" do
before :each do
@user_attr = FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:user)
# @user = FactoryGirl (:user)
User.create!(@user_attr)
end

scenario "signs me in"  do
  # login_as @user, :scope => :user
  visit '/'
  fill_in 'Login', :with => "admin@revol-tech.com.np"
  fill_in 'Password', :with => "bhaktapur"
  click_button 'Sign in'
  page.should have_content "Signed in successfully"
  Warden.test_reset! 
 end
end
```

Also my User model is set to confirmable

Comment: I finally found the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6576592/failing-to-test-devise-with-capybara

Comment: I found the solutions using 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6576592/failing-to-test-devise-with-capybara

Answer (score 2):

Instead of adding all the confirmable data points.. should use

```
@user = FactoryGirl.build(:user)
@user.skip_confirmation!
@user.save!
```

Then within your scenario

```
fill_in 'Login', :with => @user.email
fill_in 'Password', :with => @user.password
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help @bullfrog but the problem still persists. Whats weird is the when i check the user does exists in test database.

Comment: I found the solution using this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6576592/failing-to-test-devise-with-capybara