# Capybara assertions fail under Poltergeist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, capybara, poltergeist

I have the following spec:

```
# MUST BE TESTED WITH JAVASCRIPT. As you can see before, it is allowing
# the Log Out link. On a real page, that element is hidden.
it "logs out a user" do
  user = login_user
  click_link user.email
  click_link "Log Out"
  assert page.has_content?('Logged out')
  assert page.has_content?('Company Profile')
end
```

My `login_user` method is in my `spec_helper.rb` file and is as follows:

```
def login_user(admin = false)
  user = FactoryGirl.create(:user, :admin => admin)
  visit login_path
  fill_in 'Email', :with => user.email
  fill_in 'Password', :with => user.password
  click_button 'Go'
  assert page.has_content?('Logged in')
  user
end
```

That last `assert` fails when I add `, js: true` to my spec.

And when I do a `save_and_open_page` right before it, Up comes the page with zero CSS and presumably no JS either since. It's not reading the assets for some reason. I thought that when you ran tests, it would read the assets just like it does in development mode. I really need help.

Comment: The error message please? Are you using Devise? Or your Session#delete method?

Comment: No error message, unless I add one to the assertion. Assertion failed. It can't find the "Logged in" on the page when I enable :js => true. If I leave that out, it works fine. There's something about Poltergeist that is causing Capybara to not read the page.

Comment: I would suggest you to use Capybara/Rspec preferred syntax in integration tests. Instead of `assert`, you can use `page.should have_content('Logged in')`. I don't know the details but I always get helpful error messages in Rspec.

Comment: I just noticed that and adjusted, thanks. Via some debugging I found that my login action ```click_button 'Go'``` returns ```Invalid user or password``` when :js => true. Not when I don't enable js though. Really, really strange. Not using Devise, it's all from scratch. Why would login work without JS, but not with it?

Comment: If you don't have any js code attached to the form or button I really can't think out why no js works but js failed.

Comment: I found out more. See that FactoryGirl line? When js is not enabled, the Factory object is persisted. When ```js: true```, FactoryGirl does not persist the object. That's why login is failing. Why on Earth would Capybara/Poltergeist change the behavior of FactoryGirl?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6576592/failing-to-test-devise-with-capybara). This was EXTREMELY tricky. I still don't know exactly ***why*** this failed in the first place, but needless to say with `RSpec/Capybara/PhantomJS/Poltergeist/Guard/Spork/FactoryGirl` there are a LOT of moving parts.

Please follow the link to see the answer. It has to to with transactional fixtures and enabling the `DatabaseCleaner` gem. It doesn't do SO any good to state the answer twice, I will leave that one as the canonical answer.

```
UPDATE
```

Actually this problem has to do with how database connections are not shared under Poltergeist/PhantomJS. The guys at Plataformatec have a superior solution on their [blog](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2011/12/three-tips-to-improve-the-performance-of-your-test-suite/) which does not involve the use of the DatabaseCleaner gem.

IMPORTANT NOTE

For Postgres users who are also using Spork, the blog solution will not work as stated. In other words, if you put the `shared_db_connection.rb` file in your `spec/support` directory, you will get a `PG::Error connection closed` message. Leave the file in `spec/support` but remove this line:

```
  ActiveRecord::Base.shared_connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
```

And instead put that in your `Spork.each_run` block in your `spec_helper.rb` file.