# Devise login acceptance test with capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, capybara, rspec-rails

There are already a few questions on stackoverflow with possible solutions, but none of them seemed to solve my problem, thus I'm asking another one, in hope it's specific enough to not be closed as duplicate.

I am trying to test a customized login form that uses devise. The environment consists of

- rails 6.0
- rspec-rails 3.9
- capybara 3.31
- selenium-webdriver 3.142.7
- database_cleaner 1.8

The following spec is failing due to a `401 Unauthorized` response, rendering the login form again with an error message that the credentials were wrong.

```
require 'rails_helper'

feature 'Logging in' do
  background do
    FactoryBot.create :user, email: 'john.doe@example.com',
                             first_name: 'John',
                             password: 'password',
                             password_confirmation: 'password'
  end

  scenario 'with correct credentials' do
    visit new_user_session_path

    within('#user-sessions--new') do
      find('#user_email').fill_in with: 'john.doe@example.com'
      find('#user_password').fill_in with: 'password'
    end

    find('input[name="commit"]').click
    expect(page).to have_content 'John'
  end
end
```

Checking the `test.log` after temporarily disabling the parameter filters for logging, I can see that the password has been submitted properly, and the user is being created before the login attempt happens, yet the authentication fails. Entering an interactive debugging session and trying to log in manually inside the capybara's spun up browser, the login also fails. The email/password login works in development mode when creating the same user through the console, though. Right now, no other devise features that could impact the login behavior (like `confirmable`) are used.

Most of the questions I found so far advise the following points:

*Disable transactional fixtures:* My `rails_helper.rb` already contains this;

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
end
```

*Configure Database Cleaner:* This was suggested in [Failing to test Devise with Capybara](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6576592/failing-to-test-devise-with-capybara) and was also already the case before I started to implement capybara specs;

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(
      :truncation,
      except: %w[ar_internal_metadata schema_migrations]
    )
  end

  config.before :each do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after :each do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end
```

Right now I have no other Idea why this scenario could be failing except for maybe the environment in which the tests are run hot having a proper database connection. If someone has an idea that helps, I'd be happy to hear it.

Comment: What happens when you use a User.create method instead of the FactoryBot method for creating a User?

Comment: @3DPrintScanner same problem. The user is inserted into the database according to the logs but the authentication still fails. I just also checked inside the test if any users are available and the user is definitely there when the test runs. I also just created the user in the development console the same way it is created in the test environment and the login works there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Rails > 5.0 it safely shares the database connection between the tests and the app under test Capybara starts. Because of that you don't need database cleaner, and you should be using transactional tests for the speed and isolation benefits. Start by removing all references to database cleaner from your project and re-enabling transactional fixtures (the default). If that doesn't solve your issue then there's a couple of other potential issues.

1. Your factory isn't creating a valid user - Use the FactoryBot.lint functionality to verify all your factories produce valid objects before your tests - https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#linting-factories
2. You have a JS error on your page that is causing issues. In development mode each JS asset is served separately which means an error in one doesn't affect the others.  In test mode, however, the assets are all concatenated which means an error in one can cause JS in other assets not to be run. Check your browser console for any JS errors and fix them.

If none of that helps please add relevant portions of your test.log to your question

Note: You're writing your tests more verbosely than they need to be. If locating fields to fill_in by id you can just pass the id to `fill_in` and not need to use separate `find` calls for every element, you should also use the more semantic `click_button` when the element you're attempting to click qualifies as a button

```
 within('#user-sessions--new') do
  fill_in 'user_email', with: 'john.doe@example.com'
  fill_in 'user_password', with: 'password'
end

click_button('commit')
expect(page).to have_content 'John'
```

Comment: Removing database cleaner and enabling transactional fixtures solved it! The more verbose fill_in's are there because the `user_password` was not being filled for an unknown reason despite having the correct id and name.

Comment: @pduersteler Glad it worked, what error exactly did you get with the less verbose `fill_in`?

Comment: The password was not filled in at all, but just the password field.